# What is the best way to translate slugs in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, routes, translation

I'm trying to achieve full internationalization of my routes in a Rails3.1 app. I'm already using Francesc Pla's [rails-translate-routes](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes) to localize route actions and resources. The last step is to be able to translate slugs for some of my models.

Route to be translated:

```
http://myhost.com/products/pharmacy --> http://myhost.com/productos/farmacia
```

I have a nested route of the form

```
# routes.rb
match 'products/:category_slug' => "products#index"
```

I have a model Category with an instance `#<Category id: 1, slug: "pharmacy">` and I do `find_by_slug` category in my ProductsController.

Any ideas on how to do translate the `:category_slug` part of the route?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you can call translation helpers directly from your controller as long as you namespace correctly with `I18n`.

So your ProductsController could contain something like the following:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    i18n_slug = I18n.t("locale.category.#{params[:category_slug]}")
    @category = Category.find_by_slug(i18n_slug)
  end
end
```

You should probably inform yourself as to potential security risks of passing the params directly into the translation engine, though I'm not aware of any. You might also consider 
moving that into a before filter or into the application controller if it will be used in multiple controller actions.